# Hover aware slider on mobile how to keep it functional?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a video preview that built from thumbnail, and launch a slider of multiple frames on hover.
its working exellent on desktop, but on mobile its not working.

This is the function:

```
`if (jQuery(window).width() > 470) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('img').on('mouseover', function() {
        var self = this,
            i = 0,
            images = $(this).data('mouseover').split('||');
        
        (function nextImage() {
            var next = images[i++ % images.length].split('#');
            $(self).data('timeout', setTimeout(function() {
                self.src = next[0];
                nextImage();
            }, next[1] || 500));
        })();
        
    }).on('mouseout', function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
        this.src = $(this).attr('src');
    });
});         
} else {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('img').on('ontouchstart touchmove', function() {
        var self = this,
            i = 0,
            images = $(this).data('ontouchstart touchmove').split('||');
        
        (function nextImage() {
            var next = images[i++ % images.length].split('#');
            $(self).data('timeout', setTimeout(function() {
                self.src = next[0];
                nextImage();
            }, next[1] || 500));
        })();
        
    }).on('touchend', function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
        this.src = $(this).attr('src');
    });
});

}
`


This is the HTML:


`<img id="img-slider" src="image1.jpg" data-mouseover="image2.jpg||image3.jpg||image4.jpg" />`

And this is the CSS:


`
#img-slider{
    height: 117px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity: 0;
}
#img-slider:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #img-slider {
    height:150px;
  }
}`
```

On the console, i get this error (only on mobile):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ay9q.jpg)

I tried to make some changes in the original code (the one for destop) and make it work on mobile, but faild.
how can i make it work? and why i get the error only on second split function?
Thanks

Tried to make a mouseover fuction working on mobile.